# Does the existence of a power of $2$ prime-representing function $\lfloor \alpha^{2^n} \rfloor$ imply Legendre's conjecture to be true?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, constants

I am preparing a paper on the topic of prime-representing functions, and one of the referees that reviewed my paper suggested me to include references to the following state of the art article: "[Prime representing functions](http://users.utu.fi/ksmato/papers/Primerepfunc.pdf)", [K. Matomäki](http://users.utu.fi/ksmato/publications.html), Acta Math. Hungar.,128,no.4 (2010) 307--314.

The abstract of the article is:

> We construct prime-representing functions. In particular we show that
>   there exist real numbers $\alpha \gt 1$ such that:
>
> $$\lfloor \alpha^{2^n} \rfloor$$
>
> is prime for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Indeed the set consisting of such
>   numbers $\alpha$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

So basically is a refinement of [Mills'constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) that is, to my surprise, able to provide a prime representing function working in the quadratic intervals $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$ (if I did not understand wrongly, this is for big enough $n$).

My doubt regarding this is: as far as I can recall, [Mills'constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) is based on powers of three, $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$, and we still do not know if [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) is true or not, so there is not proof for a constant capable of making a prime-representing function like $\lfloor A^{2^n} \rfloor$. But according to the results of Matomäki, the study of the state of the art of prime gaps (and assuming that the [Riemann hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) is true , as it is stated in the paper) makes possible to develop such power-of-two-based Mills-like constant.

> So my question is: does the existence of such power of two Mills-like constant imply that Legendre's conjecture is true? where is the trick, or where is the point I misunderstood? maybe can the constant exist, but Legendre's conjecture can still be false without being a contradiction? Thank you!

**Update 2017/06/06**.

> My perception is that Matomäki's proof shows that the existence of the constant implies that **at least** exist **one infinite set of quadratic intervals** $[N^2,(N+1)^2]$, indeed associated to the primes generated by the constant, each one of them containing **at least one prime** (indeed the one generated by the constant). So my guessing is that it is safe to say that (1) Still Legendre's conjecture is **not** proved to be **true for all** the existing quadratic intervals $[N^2,(N+1)^2]$, (2) Legendre's conjecture **is true** for those intervals associated to the primes generated by Matomäki's constant. A confirmation or not of this reasoning would be very appreciated.

Comment: @orlp isn't it??? sure there is a trick, but I can not see it as well...

Comment: @orlp: What I have read is that if Legendre's conjecture is true, then you can find an $\alpha$ for the "middle exponent" of $2$.  But I have never heard the converse, that is, I have never heard of a proof that a prime generating function with a middle exponent of 2 (as presented in the Matomaki paper) implies Legendres conjecture.

Comment: @MarkFischler yeah, that is the point I think I am missing, but in the other hand, I also did not hear the opposite of your phrase as well: a proof that a prime generating function with a middle exponent of $2$ does not imply Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: @orlp I doubt if it the same logic could be applied,but I am not an expert: in the case of the elaboration of the classic Mills's constant,the demonstration implies a manipulation of the prime gaps (in those days Ingham's bound was the best one)that led Mills to the demonstration of the existence of a prime in $[n,(n+1)^3]$ for a big enough $n$. So it is required the existence of the prime for the constant to exist.And if the constant can not exist, then there is not a prime in the interval (for big $n$).They are linked,but that is my perception,I would really enjoy reading a good explanation.

Comment: I now understand my confusion, and it's really silly. I was constantly working with $[p, (p+1)^2]$, but Legendre's conjecture is $[p^2, (p+1)^2]$. Now that is out of the way I see no reason why this paper would imply Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: @orlp Do you understand how Mills' constant is generated ? Once we know $a_n = \lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$ we know that $a_{n+1} = \lfloor A^{3^{n+1}} \rfloor \in [a_n^3,(a_n+1)^3]$ and this is where a weaker Legendre conjecture (known true is the RH is true) is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote Professor Matomäki (thank you very much for your time and kind response!), and she kindly gave me the following explanation that I just have formatted to write the answer (basically **yes, Legendre's conjecture is true for those intervals**):

> The correspondence is the other way round, the paper uses the fact that Legendre's conjecture is true for most $N$, which is Lemma $7$ in the paper. That's the crucial ingredient which allows to take a power of $2$ in place of $3$ (or in place of $\frac{40}{19}$ following from Baker-Harman-Pintz on prime gaps).

Here is the aforementioned Lemma $7$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Legendre conjecture

> **for every**  $n$  there is a prime $ p \in [n^2,(n+1)^2]$

is the same as

> **for every** $a_0 \ge 3$ there exists $\alpha \in [a_0,a_0+1]$ such that $a_n = \lfloor \alpha^{2^n} \rfloor$ is prime for every $n \ge 1$

This is because for every $n$ and for every $k \in [a_n^2,(a_n+1)^2]$, we can refine $\alpha$ without changing $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ to obtain $$a_{n+1} =  \lfloor \alpha^{2^n} \rfloor = k$$

Comment: may I ask two questions: 1) is it floor $\lfloor \alpha^{2^n}\rfloor$ what you wanted to write or you wrote ceil instead of floor on purpose? 2) does your explanation imply that the opposite is not true? e.g. if $\lfloor \alpha^{2^n}\rfloor$ exists then it implies that Legendre is true. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @iadvd I thought you said $\lceil \alpha^{2^n} \rceil$, it works the same way with $\lfloor \alpha^{2^n} \rfloor$

Comment: I think better said would be that for every $n$, there exists a prime $p \in (n^2, (n + 1)^2)$ since $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ are obviously not prime.